# Why does Chrome at my school initially take so long to "get" the Internet?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, browser, proxy-server

My school has a number of classrooms with about twenty computers each, all running Windows 7. They're all connected to a central server for our work, and to the Internet by way of a proxy server. Our work-server accounts and local-user accounts have the same credentials. Every computer has had Firefox and Chrome pre-downloaded. My browser of choice is Chrome.

If I log in to a computer for the very first time, or for the first time in a while, it has to spend a few minutes "building my desktop". (That's not my problem.) Then, if I open Internet Explorer or Firefox, I visit any page as usual. But if I open Chrome, it won't load either of the two pages it begins with, or any other page. I keep reloading, closing tabs, closing and reopening the browser, and twiddling my thumbs, and some combination of these things manages to get it to finally work. (It's usually a few minutes, but the last time it happened the wait was forty minutes.) It then lets me log into my Chrome account. After that, I never have a problem with it, even after logging out and logging back in (at which point both the Windows environment and the Chrome browser remember my identities in each).

This is an entirely predictable phenomenon -- it happens on every single "new" computer I use. I naturally assume it has *something* to do with the proxy server. But the actual settings suggest that Chrome, just like Firefox and IE, should already know the proxy address from the get-go, and I never actually change those settings before it starts working. So what's going on?

Comment: Sounds like something to do with the proxy server.  Have you asked IT for assitance?

Comment: By default Chrome should use same proxy settings as IE. Another piece of puzzle would be if you are using Roaming or Local User accounts. Depending on account type and where your settings are stored could create a problem.